# is there a way to change for a short time cursor for the whole window/page/body in HTML / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fine working page, with a countable complexity and AJAX and so on, so far all fine, all ok; (its a somehow special editor)

In the case an AJAX action takes 'longer' (250ms im my app), I disable the whole "window" with a `div opacity 0.3` as overlay showing a "..... takes a bit ..." icon, you know this 'wait a moment' screens.

All this is fine and well working.

Now my experiaenced Users want the cursor to be changed (to a wait) imadiatly after an AJAX runs in the background.

What did I try so far:

css:

```
body.wait { cursor: wait !important; }
and 
html.wait { cursor: wait !important; }
```

and adding the class 'wait' to body

I know a solution, puting (an other) div in forground (opacity 0), but isnt there an other solution?

like `window.cursor` or something like that?

an other input: browsers behave different (yes, no news), IE does a bit better (? really) but all struggle with the embeeded SVG elements

so again my Question: is there a way to change the cursor for the page more or less ignoring CSS, HTML and DOM?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: sry, but its not a dup, because I 1) tried the solutions mentioned there, 2) have additonal SVG, and 3) the mentioned solution: "When body has the wait class, everything will show the wait cursor." I tried does not.

Comment: I'm unsure about the svg, but your question does not indicate that you tried `body.wait *`.  It is possible the svg work differently though.  Perhaps you could create a http://jsfiddle.net that better illustrates your specific problem?

Comment: @JamesMontagne thx anyhow, you triggered me for an other solution - i try it out (change style info!)

Answer (score 1):

solution if you have at least one style sheet (this is fast enough and not penetrating DOMiteration):

change the CSS Style sheet:

```
sh = document.styleSheets[0]
Wait_a_bit="* {cursor: wait !important}"
sh.insertRule(Wait_a_bit, 0)
```

before your ajax and remove it afterward:

```
sh.deleteRule(0)
```